# combining 2 if statement in excel (logic operator)

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Is it possible to combine 2 if statements in excel?

I want to combine this if

```
IF('1 aug dem post'!F7=3,"X")
```

with this if

```
IF('1 aug dem post'!$F$6='1 aug dem post'!F7,1,0)
```

I tried with or statement but it only returns true or false. I need it to return 1, 0 or X.

Is there any way to do this or any function?

Comment: It is possible to combine 2 if statements. Can you provide us with an example of what your worksheet looks like and what the expected outcome should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can combine them like this:

```
IF('1 aug dem post'!F7 = 3, "X", IF('1 aug dem post'!$F$6 = '1 aug dem post'!F7, 1, 0))
```

The second `IF` function becomes an argument of the first one.